# Trying to ignore files that begin with a "." but script not working

Tags: bash, terminal

Got a question that hopefully is just me doing a stupid mistake.

I have a script where I'm searching for specified mxf files.  At the same time I'm try ignore files beginning with a period (.) because those are the hidden files that I don't need to search.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the script. I keep getting an error when my script searches the drive and runs into a file or folder that I do not have permission for and was trying to ignore.  Can anyone help?  The script is below.

```
echo Searching for digitized INTV footage...
find /Volumes/TestingTranscode*           \
    -type f \(                            \
        -iname "*V01.*.mxf" !             \
        -iname "Avid_Mob*" !              \
        -iname ".*" !                     \
        -ipath "*Creating*"               \
    \)                                    \
    -exec /Users/admin/TestingTranscode/01_BashScripts/postfind_gw_digitize.sh {} \;
```

Comment: may be you missed excluding hidden **directories**?

Answer (score 0):

Use the prune switch for excluding a full  subtree:

find . -name ".*" -prune -o ...

I think something similar should work:

```
find /Volumes/TestingTranscode*           \ 
    -name ".*" -prune -o \
    -type f \(                            \
        -iname "*V01.*.mxf" !             \
        -iname "Avid_Mob*" !              \
        -ipath "*Creating*"               \
    \)                                    \
    -exec
    -/Users/admin/TestingTranscode/01_BashScripts/postfind_gw_digitize.sh {}
    -/\;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm super green with all of this.  How do I apply that to my script?

Comment: I modified my answer. (the comments doesn't support nice view for code examples.)

Answer (score 0):

Quick question:

Should you descend down directories which begin with a period as long as the file doesn't? Or, do you also want to exclude directories that begin with a period?

To exclude all files that start with a period:

```
$ find . \! -name ".*" -type f
```

To exclude any files or directories that begin with a period:

```
$ find . \! -path "*/.*" -name "*.mfx" -type f
```

If you get too fancy, you're better off switching to something like Perl:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use feature qw(say);

find ( sub {
          return unless -f;                       # Must be a file
          return if $File::Find::Name =~ m|/\.|;  # Remove files & dirs that starts with "."
          return unless /\.mfx$/i;                # Only MFX files
          return ....                             # More requirements....
          say $File::Find::name;
      }, "."
 );
```

A 1/2 dozen or so lines of script will save you a lot of effort in trying to get the `find` command syntax correct when things get too complex.